# What are the additional js files of the Angular.js framework for?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying out [angular.js](http://www.angularjs.org/) and I'm confused by the number of javascript files that I should import. In the 1.0.1 release there are a bunch of additional files such as:

- angular-bootstrap-1.0.1.js
- angular-loader-1.0.1.js
- angular-resource-1.0.1.js
- angular-sanitize-1.0.1.js

Naturally I have opened these files to try to understand what is their function. For instance, angular-loader has a comment that says:

```
Interface for configuring angular {@link angular.module modules}.
```

To me, it sounds like an important module, but my simple app works ok without it...

Shall I import all of them?

Comment: If you just try to open those files with any text editor you'll see what they do in the comment right at the top.

Comment: angular-bootstrap has no comments whatsoever. The other files have very lenghty comments, but it's not clear to me if they should be included in a default angular web app. For instance:
A factory which creates a resource object that lets you interact with
 * [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) server-side data sources.

Comment: Of course I have opened the files myself, but it is not clear to me if these files are mandatory or not. The simple app works fine without them.

Comment: These files are modules (or plugins) that may - but may as well not - be used along with `angular.js` to somewhat widen its functionality. They're not required; including just `angular.js` (or `angular.min.js`) would be enough.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Disclaimer: it is my thoughts. I am not core developer.

AngularJS has base ng module (angular-1.0.1.js) which all basically use and some add-on modules. If you look at the [api documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/) you will see that the table of contents on the left side is divided into blocks: ng module, ngMock module, ngCookies module, etc.

angular-bootstrap-1.0.1.js seems as bootstrap-like implementations of dropdown and tabs. I think they are mainly used on [angularjs.org](http://angularjs.org/). But can be used by anyone (thanks to the MIT license).

angular-cookies-1.0.1.js is [ngCookies module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies) which provide two services: [$cookies](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.$cookies) and [$cookieStore](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.$cookieStore).

angular-loader-1.0.1.js as far as I understand should help to setup angular (ensure that all required modules loaded, etc) in external environments.

angular-resource-1.0.1.js is [ngResource module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) which provide [$resource service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource).

angular-sanitize-1.0.1.js is [ngSanitize module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) which provide [ngBindHtml directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.directive:ngBindHtml), [linky filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.filter:linky) and [$sanitize service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.$sanitize).

Answer (score 9):

Here be the official answer to your question http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/downloading